# I want to drag and drop buttons and images all ui-elements and drag again the element inside canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-ui, dom

i want to drag the (buttons,divs,images) and drop on to the canvas and then drag  again inside the canvas. its not working properly only  (divs) i can drag and drop and again start a dragging inside canvas not on buttons and other element

thanks

```
$(init);
function init() {
var diagram = [];
var canvas = $(".canvas");




$(".tool").draggable({
  helper: "clone",
  //cursor: "move",
  cancel: false,
   });
  canvas.droppable({
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    console.log(ui.helper.prop("outerHTML"))

    var new_signature = ui.helper.is('.ui-resizable') ?
        ui.helper
      :
        $(ui.helper).clone().removeClass('tool ui-draggable ui-draggable-
       handle ui-draggable-dragging');
    $(this).append(new_signature);
    new_signature.draggable({
      helper: false
    }).resizable()

  }
 });

 }
```

[this is a link of jsfiddle for further explanation](https://jsfiddle.net/jakecigar/wngwsxw2/9/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some minor corrections you may want to consider.

**JavaScript**

```
function init() {
  var diagram = [];
  var canvas = $(".canvas");
  $(".tool").draggable({
    helper: "clone",
    cancel: false,
  });
  canvas.droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      console.log(ui.helper.prop("outerHTML"));
      var new_signature;
      if (ui.helper.is('.ui-resizable')) {
        new_signature = ui.helper;
      } else {
        new_signature = ui.helper.clone();
        new_signature.removeClass("ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle ui-draggable-dragging");
        new_signature.draggable({
          helper: false,
          containment: "parent"
        }).resizable();
      }
      $(this).append(new_signature);
    }
  });
}

$(init);
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/0gLh2h6o/

---

**Update**

Often, it is best to avoid using draggable and resizable on some things, when there are other Click events that will be handled.

I would suggest creating a wrapper, and handle, that can be used to drag the element, and then resize upon the element.

Consider this:

**HTML**

```
<div style="width:20%;float:left;border:1px solid; height:400px">
  <h6>buttons</h6>
  <div>
    <div class="fake tool button tool-1">Click</div>
    <br/>
    <div class="fake tool button tool-2">Click</div>
    <hr />
  </div>
</div>
<div style="width:78%;height:400px;float:right;border:1px solid;" class="canvas">
  <p>
    canvas
  </p>

</div>
note:i want to drag these button multiple time and once it dopped inside canvas it can be draggable inside canvas and resizable
```

**CSS**

```
.tool-1,
.tool-2 {
  width: 60px;
  height: 1.5em;
  border: 1px red solid;
  border-radius: .2em;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.tool-2 {
  border: 1px green solid;
}

.canvas .tool_wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}

.canvas .tool_wrapper .tool_handle {
  height: 10px;
  line-height: 10px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: right;
}

.canvas .tool_wrapper .tool_handle .ui-icon {
  margin-top: -.30em;
}

.canvas .tool_wrapper .ui-resizable-se {
  margin-left: -5px;
  margin-top: -5px;
}

.canvas .tool_wrapper .button {
  width: 60px;
  height: 1.5em;
  border-radius: .2em;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
function init() {
  var diagram = [];
  var canvas = $(".canvas");
  $(".tool").draggable({
    helper: "clone",
    cancel: false,
  });
  canvas.droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      console.log(ui.helper.attr("class"));
      if (ui.helper.hasClass("fake")) {
        var new_signature;
        if (ui.helper.hasClass("button")) {
          new_signature = $("<div>", {
            class: "tool_wrapper ui-widget",
            style: ui.helper.attr("style")
          });
          new_signature.css("top", (parseInt(new_signature.css("top").substr(0, -2)) - 10) + "px")
          var handle = $("<div>", {
              class: "tool_handle ui-widget-header"
            })
            .html("&nbsp;").appendTo(new_signature);
          var close = $("<span>", {
            class: "ui-icon ui-icon-close"
          }).appendTo(handle).click(function() {
            if (confirm("Are you sure you want to remove this Button?")) {
              new_signature.remove();
            }
          });
          var tool = $("<div>", {
              class: ui.helper.attr("class"),
              contenteditable: true
            })
            .html(ui.helper.html())
            .appendTo(new_signature).resizable();
          tool.css({
            width: "60px",
            height: "1.5em",
            "line-height": "inherit"
          });
          tool.removeClass("fake ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle ui-draggable-dragging");
        }
        new_signature.appendTo($(this));
        new_signature.draggable({
          handle: ".tool_handle",
          helper: false,
          containment: "parent"
        })
      }
    }
  });
}

$(init);
```

Here, we create a `div` wrapper and create a handle, with a close button, to use to move the element around. This becomes our draggable, and we can place a `button`, `div`, or `img` inside it. This allows `contenteditable` to receive it's own cl;ick event and not interfere with the click event that draggable is expecting, since it will only be looking for that on the handle.

Resizable is then assigned to the element itself to ensure that we change it's size and not just the size of the wrapper.

Comment: thankx dear but it is not working when i replace div or try to drag button.                     <button class="tool tool-1" contenteditable="true">click</button>

Comment: Please update your post with the actual code you intent to use.

Comment: sir, it is perfectly ok. thanx .only one thing is creating minor  issue on my real project.please provide any source so i can send you real project images of problem .

Comment: .i have added the fiddle please try to drag and drop the nav bar. i added, it is creating issue and same issue is for image also.                                           https://jsfiddle.net/Yousuf_007/k3ea2hwa/1/

Comment: @Khan you will want to change the class for this from `button` to something like ` navbar` and this will be a much more complex element. On the left hand side, you want pseudo representation of the element that the user will drag in. The code for this will not be too different than the button, yet it will have some different styling. Will see if I can shoot you an update.

Comment: SIR thankx alot  thankx alot ..best (y) you are great .if i need any further help can i contact you ?

Comment: sir from the same codes can i drag and drop image with some change of css?

Comment: @Khan look at how the other elements and how they have been done. It can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it works. Check the background color of the a element in fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/jakecigar/wngwsxw2/9/

```
.ui-resizable {
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: its working but once its dropped button stops dragging inside canvas..please replace div from button.it wont work once it is dropped inside canvas

Answer (score 0):

The new_signature element has position:static after it is set to draggable. It needs to be absolute.
Use Twisty's version, add this lines:
    cancel: false
after containment: "parent",
and
    new_signature.css({position: 'absolute'});
just before $(this).append(new_signature);

It worked in my test.

Comment: it is working thankx alot...but one last thing when i dropped, it stopped resizable on button.please check

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Yousuf_007/vd4a3nq9/                 please see the fiddle resizable is not working on button